# How to check if someone is referencing the dll?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

In my work we have an outside  bin library which has many many dll's.

they want to clean it up. (remove unused dlls)

out solution has many many projects.

what is the best way to check if a dll is referenced without iterating each project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) creates a nice reference graph

Answer (score 0):

Since for some reason this question is tagged ReSharper, I should note that ReSharper 6.1 (early access for this new version is coming soon) is expected to introduce a feature to find and remove unused assembly references

Comment: Here's [how the feature works](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/01/optimizing-assembly-references-with-resharper-61/) in ReSharper 6.1